# Heap corruption on output

Tags: c++

I am attempting to print some data from a class and it prints fine until he reaches the integer and then throws a heap corruption error. Can anyone explain to me why it would be doing this?

```
void Skill::Display(ostream& out){
    char* myName = getName();
    char* myDescription = getDescription();
    int myLevel = getLevel();

    out << " - " << myName << " -- " << myDescription << "[Lvl: ";

    out << myLevel << "]" << endl; //Everything up to here is fine
}//breakpoint here and it gives me heap error.
```

I don't understand why printing an int would cause a heap error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring in your getName() or getDescription() methods. Check for initialization problems and null pointers. See the advice from @Atimony as well. An improperly terminated string can cause problems as well.

Comment: good point, I forgot about the possibility of uninitialized pointers. I think nulls would just cause a segfault though.

Comment: I had a derp moment, I was double creating the chars, Once on creation and then again right before i input the values. DERP

Answer (score 2):

I think it's more likely that the error is being caused by a buffer overrun in myName or myDescription. How are they calculated? Did you remember to null terminate and take into account the buffer size?

Remember, the point where an error is detected is not necessarily the point where the error originated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with heap corruption is that the place where corruption is detected quite often has nothing to do with the place where corruption actually happens. Corruption might have happened long time ago in different method in different component.

Sounds like you have a repro. In that case the easiest way to find the offender code is to enable [Paged Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you are on Windows, or [Electric Fence](http://elinux.org/Electric_Fence) if you are on Unix. That will break your executable at exact place corruption occurs.